# subgit - how to reflect edited SVN log message in git

Tags: git, subgit

I'm using subgit to sync my git and SVN repos. I have updated a misleading log message in SVN and I would like that reflected in git. I was wondering if something like this would do the trick:

- `subgit uninstall` (on the server to stop the synchronization)
- `git checkout master` (on my local)
- `git reset --hard HEAD~5`
- `git push -f` (to reset the origin git repo back to previous revision)
- `subgit install` (to re-sync the SVN changes to git)

Am I on the right lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retranslate several latest revisions including that one for which you've edited the message. Suppose you've edited message for revision REV and the previous revision

```
PREV = REV - 1
```

In this case the following command should help:

```
subgit install --rebuild-from-revision PREV path/to/git/repository
```

Note that Git SHA-1 hashes will be changed after that.

The commands you've suggested will result into new SVN revisions without affecting the existing one. In particular `git push -f` will result into branch/trunk replacement which is not recommended. Prefer `--rebuild-from-revision` solution.